# Jquery hide 'sibling' element within same parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery, and have a problem I am not sure how to tackle.

I am creating a learning management system for teachers to assign homework to their classes. Inside of the menu shown below, when the user is on the "Class Settings" tab they should be able to un-check the box next to the class-name which would:

1. hide the assign/due date inputs, and
2. replace these inputs by making the `.unassigned` class visible.

If the user checks the box, the opposite should happen, basically like a toggle.

Here is the part I am not sure how to do: how would I even select the corresponding `<div class='assign'>  <div class='due'>  <div class='unassign'>` to toggle visibility? All of these should be siblings to the `<section>` parent that groups them together, I think.

Right now I have

```
var status = $(this).find('section .unassigned');
```

to just debug and see if I can select the elements I am trying to select, but I am not successful.

Any help/explanation would be very much appreciated.

```js
// This section handles UX feedback for class settings //
$('.class').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  var status = $(this).find('section .unassigned');
  status.css("background-color", "yellow");
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) { // When user checks box
    status.hide();
    alert('checked');
  }
  else { // When user unchecks box 
    status.show();
    alert('unchecked');
  }
});

// This section handles navigation //
function nav(arg) {
  var destination = arg.dataset.nav;
  var pages = document.querySelectorAll("[data-page]");
  var nav = document.querySelectorAll("[data-nav]");
  
  for (i = 0; i < nav.length; i++) { // Remove the class 'active' if it exists
    nav[i].classList.remove('active')
  }
  arg.classList.add('active'); 
  
  for (i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) { // Hide/show the correct pages
    if (pages[i].dataset.page != destination) {
      pages[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      if (destination == 'basic') {pages[i].style.display = "flex";}
      if (destination != 'basic') {pages[i].style.display = "block";}
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {display: block !Important}

.modal {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 20;
   right: 0; top: 0;
   width: 100%; height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
   animation-name: fadeIn;
   animation-duration: 0.4s}

.assignment-window{
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw; height: 70vh;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 0.9fr 2.5fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "asstop asstop"
    "assnav asscontent"}


/* ----------[ASS TOP]---------- */
.asstop {
  grid-area: asstop;
  padding: 24px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #581F98;}

.asstop .title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;}

.asstop .title input {
  flex: 1 1;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray}

.asstop select {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray}

.asstop button {
  margin-top: -5px;}


/* ----------[ASS NAV]---------- */
.assnav {
  grid-area: assnav;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 10%;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray}

.assnav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none}

.assnav li {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #484848;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;}
  .assnav li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #F2F2F2}
  .assnav li.active {background-color: #EEEEEE}


/* ----------[ASS CONTENT]---------- */
.asscontent {
  grid-area: asscontent;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: scroll}

.asscontent input:not([type='checkbox']), .asscontent select {
  flex: 1;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray}


/* ==== Basic Styling ==== */
.asscontent .basic {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column}

.asscontent .basic textarea {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;}

.asscontent .basic .config {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 20px;}
  .asscontent .basic input {text-align: center;}
  .asscontent .basic .points {width: 80px;}


/* ==== Attachment Styling ==== */
.asscontent .attachments {display: none}

.asscontent .attachments section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}


/* ==== Class Styling ==== */
.asscontent .class {display: none}

.asscontent .class section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

.asscontent .class label {cursor: pointer;}

.asscontent .class .unassigned {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  color: darkgray;}


/* ==== Delete Styling ==== */
.asscontent .delete {display: none;}

.asscontent .delete ul {margin-bottom: 30px;}

.asscontent .delete li {margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <nav></nav>
</head>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="assignment-window">
    <div class='asstop'>
      <div class='title'>
        <select>
          <option>✏️</option>
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Type assignment title..' value=''>
        <button class='button purple-btn'>Save Changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='assnav'>
      <ul>
        <li data-nav='basic' onclick='nav(this);' class='active'>Basic Setup</li>
        <li data-nav='attachments' onclick='nav(this);'>Attachments</li>
        <li data-nav='class' onclick='nav(this);'>Class Settings</li>
        <li data-nav='delete' onclick='nav(this);'>Delete Assignment</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='asscontent'>
      <div class='basic' data-page='basic'>
        <textarea placeholder='Type assignment directions..'></textarea>
        <div class='config'>
          <section>
            <span>Subject: </span>
            <select>
              <option>Reading</option>
              <option>Social Studies</option>
            </select>
          </section>
          <section>
            <span>Points:</span>
            <input class='points' type='text'>
          </section>
          <section>
          <span>Submission: </span>
          <select>
            <option>Require students to scan.</option>
            <option>Allow scanning or turn in button.</option>
            <option>Grade only: students don't submit.</option>
            <option>Do not allow submissions.</option>
          </select>
        </section>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='attachments' data-page='attachments'>
        <section>
          <div class='displayName'>
            <select>
              <option></option>
              <option></option>
              <option></option>
            </select>
            <input name='attach[1][title]' placeholder='Title of website..' type='text'>
          </div>
          <div class='url'>
            <input name='attach[1][url]' placeholder='Insert website URL..' type='url'>
          </div>
          <div class='visible'>
            <span>Visible: <span>
            <select name='attach[1][visible]'>
              <option>- All Students -</option>
              <option> Reading/Social</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
      <div class='class' data-page='class'>
        <section>
          <div class='name'>
            <label>
              <input type='checkbox' checked>
               Reading/Social
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class='assign'>
            <span>Assign:</span>
            <input type='date'>
          </div>
          <div class='due'>
            <span>Due:</span>
            <input type='datetime-local'>
          </div>
          <div class='unassigned' hidden>
            <span>Not assigned to this class</span>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section>
          <div class='name'>
            <label>
              <input type='checkbox'>
               Reading/Social
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class='assign' hidden>
            <span>Assign:</span>
            <input type='date'>
          </div>
          <div class='due' hidden>
            <span>Due:</span>
            <input type='datetime-local'>
          </div>
          <div class='unassigned'>
            <span>Not assigned to this class</span>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
      <div class='delete' data-page='delete'>
        <p>Deleting the assignment? The following will happen: </p>
        <ul>
          <li>All recorded submission and scores will be deleted.</li>
          <li>The assignment will be removed from student view.</li>
          <li>Student subject averages will adjust from the deleted scores.</li>
          <li>This action cannot be undone.</li>
        </ul>
        <button class='button grey-btn'>Cancel</button>
        <button class='button red-btn'>Permanently Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is searching an element having the class `unassigned` in a `section` but [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) searches through the descendents of `$(this)` which is your `checkbox`.

```
var status = $(this).find('section .unassigned');
```

Instead you could use :

```
var unassigned = $(this).closest('section').find('.unassigned');
```

[`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) will match the first parent that is a `section` element, and then `.find()` will match its children having the `unassigned` class.

```js
// This section handles UX feedback for class settings //
$('.class').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  var unassigned = $(this).closest('section').find('.unassigned');
  var assign = $(this).closest('section').find('.assign');
  var due = $(this).closest('section').find('.due');
  unassigned.css("background-color", "yellow");
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) { // When user checks box
    unassigned.hide();
    assign.show();
    due.show();
  }
  else { // When user unchecks box 
    unassigned.show();
    assign.hide();
    due.hide();
  }
});

// This section handles navigation //
function nav(arg) {
  var destination = arg.dataset.nav;
  var pages = document.querySelectorAll("[data-page]");
  var nav = document.querySelectorAll("[data-nav]");
  
  for (i = 0; i < nav.length; i++) { // Remove the class 'active' if it exists
    nav[i].classList.remove('active')
  }
  arg.classList.add('active'); 
  
  for (i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) { // Hide/show the correct pages
    if (pages[i].dataset.page != destination) {
      pages[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      if (destination == 'basic') {pages[i].style.display = "flex";}
      if (destination != 'basic') {pages[i].style.display = "block";}
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {display: block !Important}

.modal {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 20;
   right: 0; top: 0;
   width: 100%; height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
   animation-name: fadeIn;
   animation-duration: 0.4s}

.assignment-window{
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw; height: 70vh;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 0.9fr 2.5fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "asstop asstop"
    "assnav asscontent"}


/* ----------[ASS TOP]---------- */
.asstop {
  grid-area: asstop;
  padding: 24px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #581F98;}

.asstop .title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;}

.asstop .title input {
  flex: 1 1;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray}

.asstop select {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray}

.asstop button {
  margin-top: -5px;}


/* ----------[ASS NAV]---------- */
.assnav {
  grid-area: assnav;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 10%;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray}

.assnav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none}

.assnav li {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #484848;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;}
  .assnav li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #F2F2F2}
  .assnav li.active {background-color: #EEEEEE}


/* ----------[ASS CONTENT]---------- */
.asscontent {
  grid-area: asscontent;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: scroll}

.asscontent input:not([type='checkbox']), .asscontent select {
  flex: 1;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray}


/* ==== Basic Styling ==== */
.asscontent .basic {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column}

.asscontent .basic textarea {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;}

.asscontent .basic .config {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 20px;}
  .asscontent .basic input {text-align: center;}
  .asscontent .basic .points {width: 80px;}


/* ==== Attachment Styling ==== */
.asscontent .attachments {display: none}

.asscontent .attachments section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}


/* ==== Class Styling ==== */
.asscontent .class {display: none}

.asscontent .class section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

.asscontent .class label {cursor: pointer;}

.asscontent .class .unassigned {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  color: darkgray;}


/* ==== Delete Styling ==== */
.asscontent .delete {display: none;}

.asscontent .delete ul {margin-bottom: 30px;}

.asscontent .delete li {margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <nav></nav>
</head>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="assignment-window">
    <div class='asstop'>
      <div class='title'>
        <select>
          <option>✏️</option>
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Type assignment title..' value=''>
        <button class='button purple-btn'>Save Changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='assnav'>
      <ul>
        <li data-nav='basic' onclick='nav(this);' class='active'>Basic Setup</li>
        <li data-nav='attachments' onclick='nav(this);'>Attachments</li>
        <li data-nav='class' onclick='nav(this);'>Class Settings</li>
        <li data-nav='delete' onclick='nav(this);'>Delete Assignment</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='asscontent'>
      <div class='basic' data-page='basic'>
        <textarea placeholder='Type assignment directions..'></textarea>
        <div class='config'>
          <section>
            <span>Subject: </span>
            <select>
              <option>Reading</option>
              <option>Social Studies</option>
            </select>
          </section>
          <section>
            <span>Points:</span>
            <input class='points' type='text'>
          </section>
          <section>
          <span>Submission: </span>
          <select>
            <option>Require students to scan.</option>
            <option>Allow scanning or turn in button.</option>
            <option>Grade only: students don't submit.</option>
            <option>Do not allow submissions.</option>
          </select>
        </section>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='attachments' data-page='attachments'>
        <section>
          <div class='displayName'>
            <select>
              <option></option>
              <option></option>
              <option></option>
            </select>
            <input name='attach[1][title]' placeholder='Title of website..' type='text'>
          </div>
          <div class='url'>
            <input name='attach[1][url]' placeholder='Insert website URL..' type='url'>
          </div>
          <div class='visible'>
            <span>Visible: <span>
            <select name='attach[1][visible]'>
              <option>- All Students -</option>
              <option> Reading/Social</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
      <div class='class' data-page='class'>
        <section>
          <div class='name'>
            <label>
              <input type='checkbox' checked>
               Reading/Social
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class='assign'>
            <span>Assign:</span>
            <input type='date'>
          </div>
          <div class='due'>
            <span>Due:</span>
            <input type='datetime-local'>
          </div>
          <div class='unassigned' hidden>
            <span>Not assigned to this class</span>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section>
          <div class='name'>
            <label>
              <input type='checkbox'>
               Reading/Social
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class='assign' hidden>
            <span>Assign:</span>
            <input type='date'>
          </div>
          <div class='due' hidden>
            <span>Due:</span>
            <input type='datetime-local'>
          </div>
          <div class='unassigned'>
            <span>Not assigned to this class</span>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
      <div class='delete' data-page='delete'>
        <p>Deleting the assignment? The following will happen: </p>
        <ul>
          <li>All recorded submission and scores will be deleted.</li>
          <li>The assignment will be removed from student view.</li>
          <li>Student subject averages will adjust from the deleted scores.</li>
          <li>This action cannot be undone.</li>
        </ul>
        <button class='button grey-btn'>Cancel</button>
        <button class='button red-btn'>Permanently Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```